# How to change vertex.shape in R with igraph according to condition

Tags: r, dataframe, nodes, igraph, vertex

I am trying to change vertex.shape but it doesn't work :

I have a dataframe like :

```
Locus     X2     X3     Prophage
Vi_1236  Vi_456  5         yes
Vi_1254  Vi_263  6         no
Vi_1369  Vi_139  2         undef
```

And I want to get a graph with igraph on which I can color the nodes according to their centrality of betweeness and when Prophage == "yes" i want a square node , when its no a circle node and when its undef a triangle node.

So, I did :

```
phage = graph.data.frame(innerJoinDf)
vertex = ifelse(phage$prophage == "yes","square","circle")
plot.igraph(phage, vertex.label = NA, vertex.color = betweenness(phage), vertex.shape = vertex)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in .igraph.shapes[[shape[el[x, 1]]]] : 
  wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: The way your data is organised `Prophage` is an edge attribute and not a vertex attribute

Comment: So how can i do ?

Comment: So assuming that you want to use `Prophage` to assign the shape to both vertices given in `Locus` and `X2` and that `Prophage` is unique in your data for these vertices, one way you could is define a vector that holds the `Prophage` attribute, `vertex <- setNames(rep(innerJoinDf$Prophage, 2), unlist(innerJoinDf[c("Locus", "X2")]))` and then use this to update the vertex shape attribute of your graph, which is in `V(g)` e.g. `V(phage)$shape = c( "circle", "square")[(vertex[V(phage)$name] == "yes") + 1L]`

Comment: Thanks it's working but what does mean the " + 1L"

Comment: For example, `innerJoinDf$Prophage == "yes"` is a logical vector. Internally TRUE == 1
and FALSE == 0. So by adding one (1L is integer 1) we convert the logical vector to a
vector of ones and twos (which we then use for subsetting the `c( "circle", "square")` vector e.g. select the first or second element)

Comment: @user20650  It would be good to write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your data are organised in `innerJoinDf` the values in the `Prophage` are interpreted as edge attributes. You can see this by looking at your `igraph` object; where the vertex attributes are indicated by the `v` and the edge by the `e`. (You can see the actual attributes using `vertex_attr(phage)` and `edge_attr(phage)`).

```
library(igraph)

phage <- graph_from_data_frame(innerJoinDf)
phage
# IGRAPH d6af3b4 DN-- 6 3 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), X3 (e/n), Prophage (e/c)
# + edges from d6af3b4 (vertex names):
# [1] Vi_1236->Vi_456 Vi_1254->Vi_263 Vi_1369->Vi_139
```

Your code `vertex = ifelse(phage$prophage == "yes","square","circle")` did not work as you cannot access the attributes directly using the `$` notation (additionaly `Prophage` starts with an uppercase `P`). One of the ways to access is using `V(graph)` and `E(graph)` and then the `$` notation e.g. `V(phage)$name`.

As you want to use `Prophage` to assign the shape to both vertices given in `Locus` and `X2` this then assumes that `Prophage` is unique in your data for these vertices. One way to do this is to define a vector that holds the `Prophage` attribute and then use this to update the vertex shape attribute of your graph, which is stored in `V(g)` (you could of course just pass the results from the `ifelse` to the `igraph` plot function instead of explicitely adding the `shape` attribute).

```
vertex <- setNames(rep(innerJoinDf$Prophage, 2), unlist(innerJoinDf[c("Locus", "X2")])) 
vertex
# Vi_1236 Vi_1254 Vi_1369  Vi_456  Vi_263  Vi_139 
#   "yes"    "no" "undef"   "yes"    "no" "undef" 

# This seems a bit convoluted but is an attempt to match by vertex name rather than order
V(phage)$shape <- ifelse(vertex[V(phage)$name] == "yes", "square", "circle")
# or
# V(phage)$shape <- c( "circle", "square")[(vertex[V(phage)$name] == "yes") + 1L]
V(phage)$shape 
# [1] "square" "circle" "circle" "square" "circle" "circle"
```

---

Data

```
innerJoinDf=read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Locus     X2     X3     Prophage
Vi_1236  Vi_456  5         yes
Vi_1254  Vi_263  6         no
Vi_1369  Vi_139  2         undef")
```